# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'stickers' cannot be null Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

Hi everyone im having this issue with a row on my posts table.

This is the form:

```
                    {{ Form::label('title', ' Título', array('class' => 'fa fa-pencil')) }}

                    {{ Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '', 'maxlength' => '255', 'placeholder' => 'Ingresar Título')) }}

                    {{ Form::label('body', ' Contenido', array('class' => 'fa fa-pencil-square-o')) }}

                    {{ Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '', 'placeholder' => 'Redactar Contenido']) }}

                    {{ Form::submit('Publicar', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}


                </div>
            </div> <!-- col-md-8 end -->


            <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <h3 class="text-center">Categoría e imágen</h3>
                <hr>


                     <br> <hr>

                    {{ Form::label('stickers', ' Etiqueta', array('class' => 'fa fa-tags')) }}
                    {{ Form::text('stickers', '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'maxlength' => '20', 'placegolder' => 'Ingresar Etiqueta')) }}

                    <br> <hr>
                    {{ Form::label('postimg', ' Seleccionar Imagen', array('class' => 'fa fa-picture-o')) }}
                    {{ Form::file('postimg') }}

                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is the Posts Migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('stickers');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->string('postimg');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
}
```

And this is part of my Controller "PostsController" :

```
public function create()
{
    return view('posts.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // validate the data
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
        ));

    // store in database
    $post = new Post;

    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->body = $request->body;
    $post->stickers = $request->stickers;
    $post->postimg = $request->postimg;

    $post->save();

    Session::flash('success', 'La publicación se ha creado correctamente');

    // redirect to another page
    return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    return view('posts.show')->withPost($post);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}
```

The sticker row belongs to posts table on my database, so when i post the data  get that error message. It was working perfectly yesterday but y moved some folders and accidentally i delete part of the code so i wrote it again but with that bug, and another one that this community helped to fix.

Thanks a lot

Comment: It doesn't look like you are requiring stickers in your form, edit the migration to make this property `->nullable()`

Comment: Can you show how your model is structured? To see if you have in your model you are sending the data through the property fillable

Comment: Actually my Posts model is empty, i'm not working on it yet. It was working fine yesterday as i said but trying to fix it i get stuck there

Comment: EddyTheDove gave the answer, so I asked you to show your model to confirm that you were using the fillable property.

Comment: @EdwardPalen actually that wasn't the answer. The problem was the class="form-control" don't ask me why but it was working with that class yesterday as far i remember, i decided to remove that class and voila.. now run smooth.

Comment: But in this case a bootstrap style class can not generate a registry error in the DB, you can still review your model, because this error can be generated regularly by not using this property in the model.

Comment: You're right, i'm working on Posts model right now to improve a best functionality on my project. Thank you so much for your time, i appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

In your model, add 'stickers' to the fillable array

```
protected $fillable = ['stickers']; //and any other mass asignable field.
```

Comment: i get this error:

TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:

Comment: Either you don't have csrf token in your form, or your token already expired. Do you use `Form::open()` ?

Comment: Ok check the layout of your file. It seems you you split the form in multiple part. I would recommended opening the form before `<div class='row'></div>` so everything else is enclosed inside. Anyway, your html file is not clearly seen So I can't tell if you are actually breaking your form or not. Try to view your source and check that your form has hidden input with `name="_token"` within.

Comment: Thank you, i did it :D the problem was this:

'maxlength' => '20' 

i took it off and problem solved thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

if nullable in stickers column
add nullable() chain method

```
$table->string('stickers')->nullable();
```

Comment: Thank you, i did it :D the problem was this:

'maxlength' => '20' 

i took it off and problem solved thanks a lot.

Actually when i did a new post without the image file field i get the same error, so my stickers table is a string of 255 chars and i limited it to 25 with parsley.css and parsley.js so data from stickers never goes out from my form. Thank you guys